# Rails 5: Can't find record with friendly id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I just add friendly_id to my application and everything works smooth except one line of code gives me an error.

I get the following error when I try to order a wine from my favorites view.

```
can't find record with friendly id: "#<Wine::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x6133278>"


  private
  def set_wine
    @wine = Wine.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
```

The is the line in my wines view:

```
<div class="col-md-3 right">
 <%= link_to "Bestellen", wine_path(@wines), class: "btn btn-form" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably `@wines` is a collection, not a single object.

Comment: I deleted .friendly. from the set_wine method and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: The issue lies with `wine_path(@wines)`. Here the `@wines` must be a collection. Make sure it is a single object.

Comment: When I change the line to @wine, I get the error no route machtes missing required key [:id ]

Comment: If I'm right, you must be iterating `@wines` in the view, try `<%= link_to "Bestellen", wine_path(wine), class: "btn btn-form" %>`

Comment: Alright, solved it. I had a <% current_user.favorite.each do |favorite| %>, so I changed to wine_path(favorite.wine), now everything works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't find record with friendly id:
>   Wine::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x6133278

The problem is `@wines` is a **collection**, not a **single object**. So when you have `wine_path(@wines)`, the *collection* is passed as an `id` to the controller method while the `friendly_id` expects a *single record*. You must change

```
<%= link_to "Bestellen", wine_path(@wines), class: "btn btn-form" %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Bestellen", wine_path(favorite.wine), class: "btn btn-form" %>
```

to resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error might also be triggered when you have not updated the records from before friendly id within your database

Then run `YouModel.find_each(&:save)` from the rails console.

Answer (score 0):

For me it the error occurred because I was using mobility. You shoud add to your model

```
friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :mobility
```

instead of

```
friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged
```